# Unable to login to Django admin after changing SESSION_COOKIE_NAME

Tags: django, python-3.x, authentication, admin, session-cookies

I want to change the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` because it's set incorrectly on a production server. Due to this, I also need to change the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` to something else. Otherwise there'll be two cookies with the same name and different domains on the users side, because it's already in production. With these two cookies, the user will have trouble logging in.

This would normally be fine, but now the problem.

Just after I changed the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` (so I haven't even changed the `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` yet), I am unable to login into the admin console. I can see the cookie with the new name being set. The application itself has no problems and users can login without problems, which is strange because it's the same authentication.

What I've tried:

1. Deleting all session on the server site
2. Private mode
3. Other Browser
4. Flushing all possible caches on the server but might have mist one.
5. Checking for hardcoded session names, but there are not.

What else could I possibly check? If I set the `SESSION_COOKIE_NAME` back to what it was, I can log in again. This issue only happens on the production server; not locally, and on not on the test server, which makes it hard to test.

Any ideas?

Comment: Try setting the local configuration just like the one in the production and then test it. After testing it, try running your project locally using wsgi file (gunicorn?) on port 8000 and test again. If the login still works, then it might be an issue in the nginx/apache configuration. In my case, I had `SESSION_COOKIE_DOMAIN` configured but I used a different domain for the testing.